# Muse Uplifts in Eclipse Phase

Tags: eclipse-phase

Is there any guidance in EP for a skilled programmer PC to eventually uplift their muse? This could of course have disastrous consequences... but i think a distinct part of Eclipse Phase is trying dangerous, well-intentioned ideas, and having to roleplay them out.

Given that transhumans are stated as often forming attachments to NPCs, it seems likely that someone might realize the limitations of their friend and want to help them out...

EDIT : I think part of the question was lost when i first typed it up and i didn't notice. The sorta released but not fully book Transhuman deals with infolife a lot and notes that AI systems that show potential are occasionally uplifted to AGI, especially game NPCs and muses. But what i'm looking for in the question if anyone's done it in game or has any ideas of how this might play out mechanically, since Transhuman doesn't go much farther than saying "it happens."

Comment: Hmm, we really don't handle "Does anyone want to speculate" questions well, here, as they're not great for the Q&A format. Could you be more precise about the criteria you'd use to decide the "best" speculative answer?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that Vigilant is looking for the best mechanical system to handle the eventual transformation of a muse into a full blown AGI.

Comment: What Kyle said. Will modify the question again. We basically have canon constraints saying something is clearly possible, but no way guidance on how to handle it happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. *Transhuman* adds an AGI background called Emergent AGI Uplift for normal AIs that were later reprogrammed into AGIs. It's on *Transhuman* pg. 78.

I'd say to play it out make it a long term Programming Task-Action. Look at the background I told you about for some idea of what sort of personality traits your Muse-cum-AGI might have.

Answer (score 3):

Based only on the core rulebook (there could be something contradicting this answer in other books), I'd say it is practically impossible to "uplift" a muse. Here are a few reasons.

### AI is fundamentally different from AGI

Most AGIs emulate human brain in software, which is why they can be sleeved in a biomorph. This is (I suspect) mostly done not because there's a particular benefit to biobrains, but in an effort to make AGIs more "human". AI, however, is not intended to relate to humanity, so it is not designed to operate in such a fashion. They learn, but they don't improve. While still likely a neural net rather than an "if-then-else" procedural code written by humans, AIs would probably operate in a different fashion than AGIs. Uplifts, by comparison, are based on regular animals whose brains are biological and operate similarly to those of humans.

### Adult animals don't get uplifted

You can't take your favourite pet and uplift it. Rather, this requires fundamental genetic manipulation that changes the nature of the species in order to allow it to develop sentience. Uplifts are born uplifted.

### AGIs are brought up, not made

Relating to the previous points, AGIs go through their own process of growing up, gradually developing their capabilities and personality. It is not a question of giving an AI more processing power and removing artificial restrictions placed on it.

With all this in mind, making an AGI version of a muse would likely require creating some sort of personality template based on it, to be used as a seed for a new AGI to be grown out of. Which means the result would *not* be a "real boy" version of your muse, but a new person that may sometimes remind you of your muse. This process would also take years, even in accelerated time.

Which means your best bet would probably be to carry the developing AGI with you in a ghostrider module, while still using the AI muse as a personal aide. In effect, you'd have its uplifted child with you, that may, eventually, grow up to replace it. If it's willing.

Comment: Transhuman discusses Uplifting existing AI systems as an AGI orgin, there's even a trait your AGI can take for it. So Posthuman Studios seems to acknowlege it's possible, it even lists Muses as one of the most likely candidates for it, because they already have a lot of human centric programming. I'll update the question to make things a bit more clear.